# Using JarURLInputStream for JavaFX Image

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

in my application I'm using the `Image` class of JavaFX with `InputStream`s. The `InputStream` is provided by calling `URL.openStream()` which works great with URLs pointing to files. However, in case I have an URL of the form `jar:file:C:/some.jar!/someImage.bmp`, the image is not loaded properly. Here is the snippet I'm experementing with:

```
 InputStream stream = url.openStream();
 Image image = new Image(stream);

 StackPane stackLayout = new StackPane();
 stackLayout.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

 Stage stage= new Stage(new Scene(stackLayout));
 stage.setScene(scene);
 stage.show();
```

I verified that the URL is correct by using

```
Files.copy(stream, new File("copy-image.bmp").toPath());
```

which results in a copy of the file within the jar archive. I think there is something wrong with the `Image` class of JavaFX (I'm using `2.2.67-b01`).

Comment: Can you explain "not loaded properly"? What exactly happens? And do you get the same results if you use `Image image = new Image(url.toExternalForm());`?

Comment: With "not loaded properly" I mean that the `Stage` is only a small window not displaying the image. During the initialization of the `Image` an error seems to occur because the `error` property of the image object gets set. I do not get any further errors. I also noticed that since `JavaFX 8.0` there is `Image.getException()` which would probably tell the underlying error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more testing I figured out that this obviously is a bug in (at least) `JavaFX 2.2.67-b01`. The problem is not related to the streams but to the bit depth of the image to load: 24-bit images can be loaded without problem whereas trying to load a 32-bit image results in an error.

Switching to `JDK 1.8.0_31` which comes with `JavaFX 8.0.31-b13` solves the problem.

Comment: Yes: looks like this is a [known bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32213) that was fixed in 8u20.